# Give an example of two sets (A and B) for which $(A \cup B) \backslash B \neq A$ - are my answers correct?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Basically the only two answers I could come up with are:

1.$A = B$, so combining them and then subtracting $B$ leaves $\emptyset$.

2.$A \subseteq B$, same logic as $1.$, adding them together and then removing $B$ leaves $\emptyset$.

Are there other legit solutions?

Answer (score 3):

We have $(A\cup B)\setminus B\ne A$ if and only if $A\cap B\ne\emptyset$.

By the way your examples are correct only if $A\ne\emptyset$.

Comment: I was about to write the same thing as you in slightly different words, though. I will add just one more thing:
$$(A \cup B) \setminus B = A \setminus ( A \cap B)$$

Answer (score 1):

Since $(A\cup B)\setminus B = (A\cup B)\cap B^c = (A\cap B^c)\cup (B\cap B^c) = A\setminus B$, you have that $$(A\cup B)\setminus B\neq A$$
if and only if $A\setminus B \neq A$. Now, intuitively, $A\setminus B$ is the set of all elements of $A$ which are not in $B$. This will be the same as $A$ if none of the elements of $A$ will be in $B$, do you agree? If so, try to prove this proposition.

Comment: sorry for asking but what's the $c$ stand for?

Answer (score 0):

Your answers are correct if $A$ is not empty, but they are not the only possibilities.
Draw a diagramm of the situation.

Adding $B$ to $A$ and then removing $B$ is the same as just removing all elements of $B$ from $A$.

$(A\cup B)\setminus B = A \setminus B$

This will be the same as $A$ iff the intersection is empty, since in that case no elements from $A$ are removed.

Further solutions to your questions are therefore examples where $A\cap B\neq\emptyset$.

For example $A = \{1, 2\}, B = \{2,3\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's just calculate the answer by simplifying:
\begin{align}
& (A \cup B) \setminus B \;\not=\; A \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"definition of $\;\ \not\ \;$; set extensionality"} \\
& \lnot \langle \forall x :: x \in (A \cup B) \setminus B \;\equiv\; x \in A \rangle \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"definition of $\;\setminus\;$; definition of $\;\cup\;$"} \\
& \lnot \langle \forall x :: (x \in A \lor x \in B) \land x \not\in B \;\equiv\; x \in A \rangle \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"logic: use $\;x \not\in B\;$ on other side of $\;\land\;$"} \\
& \lnot \langle \forall x :: (x \in A \lor \text{false}) \land x \not\in B \;\equiv\; x \in A \rangle \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"logic: simplify"} \\
& \lnot \langle \forall x :: x \in A \land x \not\in B \;\equiv\; x \in A \rangle \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"logic: $\;P \land Q \equiv P\;$ and $\;\lnot P \lor Q \;$ are two ways of writing  $\;P \Rightarrow Q\;$"} \\
& \lnot \langle \forall x :: x \not\in A \;\lor\; x \not\in B \rangle \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"logic: DeMorgan"} \\
& \langle \exists x :: x \in A \;\land\; x \in B \rangle \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"definition of $\;\cap\;$"} \\
& \langle \exists x :: x \in A \cap B \rangle \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"basic property of $\;\emptyset\;$"} \\
& A \cap B \not= \emptyset \\
\end{align}

So the answer is: any sets $\;A,B\;$ which have at least one element in common.